# Remove item from array lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

i’ve two array and I want to remove entries that exist in array 2 from array 1

of course I can loop and create new array but my question is if lodash have some util that can help …

```
var array1 = [“user1”,”user2", “user3", “user4”];


var array2 = [“user1”, “user3"];
```

I want that **array1** will have after the remove

```
var array1 =[”user2", “user4”];
```

I saw that lodash have this but is there is better way ?

```
var evens = _.remove(array, function(n) {
  return n % 2 == 0;
});
```

Comment: You need to use the right quotation marks: `'`, `"` or ```

Comment: And that lodash script wont work. Its to remove every second entry. So what have you tried beside of that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With lodash you can use `_.difference(array, [values])` Where `array` is the array to inspect, and `[values]` are the values to exclude.

Check documentation at https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#difference

```
var array1 = ['user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'user4'];
var array2 = ['user2', 'user4'];

array1 = _.difference(array1, array2); //['user1','user3'];
```

Comment: thanks but you added it to `filteredArray ` I need it to be in `array1` , any idea?

Comment: @tjholwik You can also use `_.pullAll(array, values)` if you want the target array to be mutated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a vanilla JS solution, you can concat your two arrays and filter out duplicated items:

```js
var array1 = ['user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'user4'];
var array2 = ['user1', 'user3'];

array1 = [...array1, ...array2].filter((e, i, self) => self.indexOf(e) === self.lastIndexOf(e));

console.log(array1);
```

If you cannot use `ES6 spread operator (...)`, use `array.prototype.concat`:

```js
var array1 = ['user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'user4'];
var array2 = ['user1', 'user3'];

array1 = array1.concat(array2).filter((e, i, self) => self.indexOf(e) === self.lastIndexOf(e));

console.log(array1);
```

Comment: I feel that this does not answer OP's question. He was looking for a way to do this with the lodash library

Comment: I got lots of error with the `[…` any idea? this is how the code should work?

Comment: @ChiragRavindra  It's not lodash, but on SO it's sometimes nice to show a pure Javascript solution too,.. @ Faly should maybe mention this at the start of his post though.

Comment: @tjholwik  Looks like your running a not so great browser,.  There is a transpile option on snippets, maybe try that.

Comment: @tjholwik It's maybe you cannot use ES6: use `array.concat` instead: array1.concat(array2).filter(...);